# Multiply two lists element by element in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list

How can I multiply the elements of two lists in Haskell, two by two?
Basically if I have [1,2,3] and [2,3,4] I want to get [2,6,12].

Answer (score 39):

```
zipWith (*) [1,2,3] [2,3,4]
```

A useful way of finding a function such as `zipWith` is [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/). There, you can enter in the type of the function you're looking for, and it will try to find matching functions in the standard libraries.

In this case you're looking for a function to combine two lists of `Int`s into a single list of `Int`s using a combiner function `(*)`, so this would be your query: [`(Int -> Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]`](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(Int%20-%3E%20Int%20-%3E%20Int)%20-%3E%20%5BInt%5D%20-%3E%20%5BInt%5D%20-%3E%20%5BInt%5D). Hoogle will even find the correct function if you change the order of the arguments.

Comment: More importantly, in this case (since the actual type of zipWith is (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]), Hoogle will unify your query with any generic type parameters...